# Phpunit runs in shell but fails in Jenkins'

Tags: jenkins, phpunit

When I run PhpUnit tests in shell, they run OK, but when run from Jenkin's build step (Execute Shell), it fails with:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3868615221631158667.sh
+ phpunit --log-junit trunk/tests/phpunit_results.xml --bootstrap trunk/tests/bootstrap.php trunk/tests/
E_WARNING: mkdir(): No such file or directory

in Nette/common/Configurator.php(255) 
in Nette/common/Configurator.php(255) mkdir()
in Nette/common/Configurator.php(141) Nette\Configurator->getCacheDirectory()
in trunk/tests/bootstrap.php(14) Nette\Configurator->createRobotLoader()
in phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php(93) include_once()
in phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php(77) PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load()
in phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(808) PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad()
in phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(586) PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap()
in phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(141) PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments()
in phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(132) PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run()
in local/bin/phpunit(586) PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I found some similar questions, but none of them answered/fixed my problem.

Here is the result of running from shell:

```
user@server:~/$ phpunit --log-junit trunk/tests/phpunit_results.xml --bootstrap trunk/tests/bootstrap.php trunk/tests/
ccccPHPUnit 4.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.
.......
Time: 128 ms, Memory: 6.75Mb
OK (7 tests, 8 assertions)
```

I welcome every suggestion.

Comment: Why are you using different command in Jenkins an in shell?

Comment: Sorry, it was a "copy-paste" error. Of course the commands are the same.

Comment: "Solved"(bypassed), the problem is, obviously, that php as it is on my server cannot create directories (dont ask me why). I simply modified my script to create all directories the framework needs (namely empty temp/)